# Express JWT Remember Me?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, jwt

I'm currently using Vue in the frontend and Express in the backend, and using Express's `JSONWebToken` plugin to handle authentication. But right now, I have no idea how to store the jwt safely in the cookie, and how can I get the User object from it. I found lots of blog posts, tutorials, etc, but none of them meets my needs. Thanks a lot for this!!

Comment: Can you show a bit of your code on login route in express and login function in Vue and what you've tried?

Answer (score -1):

Basically the JWT is kind of safe in a httpOnly cookie. There are still some real issues with that. To fix the issues with a simple accessToken, you need to create a additional refreshToken (take a look at that [article](https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/)

You store the refreshToken in a cookie and the accessToken in a simple cache.

First you need to verify the sent jwt. You do that with the `verify` method from the jwt package.

If it was successfull you get a payload back from the `verify` method. In the payload is the user and you can parse it to your object.

This is a basic javascript implementation:

```js
export const isAuth = ({ context }, next) => {
  const authorization = context.req.headers['authorization'];

  if (!authorization) {
    throw new Error('not authenticated!');
  }

  try {
    const token = authorization.split(' ')[1];
    const payload = verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET!);
    context.payload = payload;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw new Error('not authenticated!');
  }

  return next();
};
```